# Most frequent and least duplicate frequent number in array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, frequency

I'm trying to find the most frequent number and the least frequent duplicate number in an array E.g

[7, 5, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 8, 7, 0, 7, 5, 2, 9, 7, 9, 3, 4, 6]

These are the duplicate number in the array above:

1. "7" appears (4 times).
2. "5" appears (4 times).
3. "6" appears (3 times).
4. "4" appears (2 times).

"7" and "5" are the most frequent number, 
"4" is the least frequent duplicate.

When I tried to code, I was able to get the number 7, but then I don't know how to implement the least frequent.

This is the code I wrote:

```
String[] numbers = "7564655870752979346".split("");
        String elements = "";
        int count = 0;
        for (String tempElement : numbers) {
            int tempCount = 0;
            for (n = 0; n < numbers.length; n++) {
                if (numbers[n].equals(tempElement)) {
                    tempCount++;
                    if (tempCount > count) {
                        elements = tempElement;
                        //  System.out.println(elements);
                        count = tempCount;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Frequent number is: " + elements + " It appeared " + count+" times");
```

My solution above only prints out 7, and I don't know how to check for the least duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function to find Min Repeated number(started from 2)

```
public static String findMin(String[] numbers, int counter) {
    int count = 0;
    String elements = "";
    for (String tempElement : numbers) {
        int tempCount = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < numbers.length; n++) {
            if (numbers[n].equals(tempElement)) {
                tempCount++;
                if (tempCount > counter) {
                    count = 0;
                    break;
                }
                if (tempCount > count) {
                    elements = tempElement;
                    //  System.out.println(elements);
                    count = tempCount;
                }
            }
        }
        if(count == counter) {
            return elements;
        }
    }
    if(count < counter) {
        return "";
    }
    return elements;
}
```

A loop over numbers:

```
String x = "";
int c = 2;
do {
    x = findMin(numbers, c ++);
} while(x == "");
```

The whole code will be

```
public class X {

  public static String findMin(String[] numbers, int counter) {
    int count = 0;
    String elements = "";
    for (String tempElement: numbers) {
      int tempCount = 0;
      for (int n = 0; n < numbers.length; n++) {
        if (numbers[n].equals(tempElement)) {
          tempCount++;
          if (tempCount > counter) {
            count = 0;
            break;
          }
          if (tempCount > count) {
            elements = tempElement;
            //  System.out.println(elements);
            count = tempCount;
          }
        }
      }
      if (count == counter) {
        return elements;
      }
    }
    if (count < counter) {
      return "";
    }
    return elements;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] numbers = "756655874075297346".split("");
    String elements = "";
    int count = 0;
    for (String tempElement: numbers) {
      int tempCount = 0;
      for (int n = 0; n < numbers.length; n++) {
        if (numbers[n].equals(tempElement)) {
          tempCount++;
          if (tempCount > count) {
            elements = tempElement;
            //  System.out.println(elements);
            count = tempCount;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    String x = "";
    int c = 2;
    do {
      x = findMin(numbers, c++);
    } while (x == "");

    System.out.println("Frequent number is: " + elements + " It appeared " + count + " times");

    System.out.println("Min Frequent number is: " + x + " It appeared " + (c - 1) + " times");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I tried to use this number "3620035681863138685" It prints out 3 as the most frequent, whilst "8" and "6" appeared as many times as the "3". How can I then make all the highest frequency appear and I select the one that is higher in the case of the above number, 8 would higher as it's higher than 6 and 3.

Comment: For that case, The solution I suggest is to count all numbers' Repetition and store them in an array and then choose the numbers you want from that array. @kingamada

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Count the number of times each digit appears.  Use an array of counts, one for each distinct digit.
2. Find the position in the array of counts with count == 2.

Implementation ... is for you to do.  But you will need to find a way to convert a `String` containing one digit into an integer.   (Hint: search the javadocs!)